# Is pip python-docx and docx only supported python version?

Tags: python-2.7, python-3.5, docx, python-docx

I was trying to move from `python 2.7` to `python 3.5`, however, my download documents (.docs) function is not working in `python 3.5`. It works working well in `python 2.7`. Both `pip` has been installed in the project in the latest version.

Comment: Perhaps you could raise this issue with the developer: https://github.com/python-openxml/python-docx/issues. Based on his docs only upto Python 3.4 is supported: https://pypi.org/project/python-docx/.

Comment: issue raised to the developer, thanks for the quick responded!

Comment: `python-docx` should work just fine in Python 3.5. Please describe specifically how it is "not working" and maybe we can help you.

Comment: apparently the download button function are able to download the .docx file in python 2.7. while in python3.5, it ignore this function which it act like there's no docx pip installed.